# Poetry - Figure out the latest version which is compatible with other dependencies

Tags: python-poetry

Using poetry, sometimes when checking for dependency Poetry will indicate that you can't install something because of compatibility issues.

For example, I have on my project `numpy==1.19.2`. Now when I try to install `pandas` I get the following

```sh
$: poetry add pandas

The currently activated Python version 3.6.9 is not supported by the project (>=3.8,<3.11).
Trying to find and use a compatible version. 
Using python3.9 (3.9.7)
Using version ^1.3.4 for pandas

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.6s)

  SolverProblemError

  Because no versions of pandas match >1.3.4,<2.0.0
   and pandas (1.3.4) depends on numpy (>=1.20.0), pandas (>=1.3.4,<2.0.0) requires numpy (>=1.20.0).
  So, because my_project depends on both numpy (1.19.2) and pandas (^1.3.4), version solving failed.
```

How can I figure out which `pandas` version should I install to be compatible with my version of `numpy`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you execute a dry run of the pandas package addition with the `*` version qualifier it should resolve to the latest version that is compatible with your other dependencies:

```
poetry add pandas@* --dry-run
```

You will see the exact version of pandas that would be installed in the command output. You can then use that version to update the version qualifier in your `pyproject.toml` file.

Alternatively, use the `*` qualifier directly in the `pyproject.toml` file as follows:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
...
pandas = "*"
...
```

Comment: This works for me only if I add surrounding quotes, e.g. `poetry add "pandas@*" --dry-run`